# How should I permission my AWS Lambdas to be able to query OpenSearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, opensearch

I have an AWS OpenSearch cluster configured with an IAM master user role. I have an AWS Lambda which I want to be able to query both OpenSearch and other AWS services like DynamoDB. I don't want to modify the OpenSearch master user role to be able to access other AWS services - it should have zero permissions.

My current solution is letting my Lambda call assumeRole to assume the master user role before querying OpenSearch. Is this the approved way to do it? Seems like it would be more efficient not to have to do the assume role step. And it has the downside that the Lambda then has full access to OpenSearch - I would prefer to give it more granular permissions, e.g. only `es:ESHttpGet`.

This AWS documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/ac.html seems to imply that you can set a resource-based access policy on domain setup which grants permissions to specific users. But I tried creating a maximally permissive policy and I still can't access the domain except as the master role. Am I misunderstanding the docs?

The permissive access policy I tried to use:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:eu-west-1:REDACTED:domain/*/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm implementing something like that at the moment and it's not quite finished, but I am using API Gateway and a Lambda authoriser function to allow basic authentication. You could try that. The policy I have is almost the same as yours except after domain I have the name of the domain, not a star. I also have vpcs for security locked down to a cidr range.

Comment: Thanks - so does your Lambda call the OpenSearch APIs without having to assume an OpenSearch master user IAM role?